# Feature Importance using Imbalanced-learn library

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, imblearn

The [imblearn](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.ensemble.BalancedBaggingClassifier.html) library is a library used for unbalanced classifications. It allows you to use `scikit-learn` estimators while balancing the classes using a variety of methods, from undersampling to oversampling to ensembles.

**My question is however, how can I get feature improtance of the estimator after using `BalancedBaggingClassifier` or any other sampling method from imblearn?**

```
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from imblearn.ensemble import BalancedBaggingClassifier 
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, class_sep=2,weights=[0.1, 0.9], n_informative=3, n_redundant=1, flip_y=0, n_features=20, n_clusters_per_class=1, n_samples=1000, random_state=10)
print('Original dataset shape {}'.format(Counter(y)))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,random_state=0)
bbc = BalancedBaggingClassifier(random_state=42,base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion=criteria_,max_features='sqrt',random_state=1),n_estimators=2000)
bbc.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all estimators in `sklearn` allow you to get feature importances (for example, `BaggingClassifier` doesn't). If the estimator does, it looks like it should just be stored as `estimator.feature_importances_`, since the `imblearn` package subclasses from `sklearn` classes. I don't know what estimators `imblearn` has implemented, so I don't know if there are *any* that provide `feature_importances_`, but in general you should look at the `sklearn` [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier) for the corresponding object to see if it does.

You can, in this case, look at the feature importances for each of the estimators within the `BalancedBaggingClassifier`, like this:

```
for estimator in bbc.estimators_:
    print(estimator.steps[1][1].feature_importances_)
```

And you can print the mean importance across the estimators like this:

```
print(np.mean([est.steps[1][1].feature_importances_ for est in bbc.estimators_], axis=0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but iterating over the estimators even with a feature_importance_ feature doesn't work. It results in the following error: `Pipeline' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_`

Comment: I've fixed the solution to account for this and tested it - it should work now!

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut around this, however it is not very efficient. The `BalancedBaggingClassifier`uses the [RandomUnderSampler](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html?highlight=randomundersampler) successively and fits the estimator on top. A for-loop with RandomUnderSampler can be one way of going around the pipeline method, and then call the Scikit-learn estimator directly. This will also allow to look at feature_importance:

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
rus=RandomUnderSampler(random_state=1)

my_list=[]
for i in range(0,10): #random under sampling 10 times
    X_pl,y_pl=rus.sample(X_train,y_train,)
    my_list.append((X_pl,y_pl)) #forming tuples from samples

X_pl=[]
Y_pl=[]
for num in range(0,len(my_list)): #Creating the dataframes for input/output
    X_pl.append(pd.DataFrame(my_list[num][0]))
    Y_pl.append(pd.DataFrame(my_list[num][1]))

X_pl_=pd.concat(X_pl) #Concatenating the DataFrames
Y_pl_=pd.concat(Y_pl)

RF=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2000,criterion='gini',max_features=25,random_state=1)
RF.fit(X_pl_,Y_pl_) 
RF.feature_importances_
```

Answer (score 0):

According to scikit learn documentation, you can use impurity-based feature importance on classifications, that don't have their own using some sort of `ForestClassifier`.
Here my `classifier` doesn't have `feature_importances_`, I'm adding it directly.

```
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)

...
...

forest = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=classifier.n_estimators,
                              random_state=classifier.random_state)

forest.fit(x_train, y_train)
classifier.feature_importances_ = forest.feature_importances_
```