# feature importance bagging classifier and column names

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, random-forest, prediction

I already referred these two posts:

- [Feature Importance using Imbalanced-learn library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284107/feature-importance-using-imbalanced-learn-library)
- [Feature importances - Bagging, scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333573/feature-importances-bagging-scikit-learn)

Please don't mark this as a duplicate.

I am trying to get the feature names from a bagging classifier (which does not have inbuilt feature importance).

I have the below sample data and code based on those related posts linked above

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
clf = BaggingClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier())
clf.fit(X, y)

feature_importances = np.mean([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in clf.estimators_], axis=0)
```

but this outputs only the feature importance (shown below) but I also want the feature names.

```
feature_importances 
# array([0.15098599, 0.27608213, 0.33606019, 0.23687169])
```

How can I find the corresponding feature names for these feature importance values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the `load_iris` function without any parameters, this way the return of the function will be a `Bunch` object (dictionary-like object) with some attributes. The most relevant, for your use case, would be `bunch.data` (feature matrix), `bunch.target` and `bunch.feature_names`.

```py
...

bunch = load_iris()
X = bunch.data
y = bunch.target
feature_names = bunch.feature_names

clf = BaggingClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(), random_state=42)
clf.fit(X, y)

feature_importances = np.mean([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in clf.estimators_], axis=0)

output = {fn:fi for fn,fi in zip(feature_names,feature_importances)}
print(output)
```

```py
{
    'sepal length (cm)': 0.008652347823679744,
    'sepal width (cm)': 0.01945400672681583,
    'petal length (cm)': 0.539297348817521,
    'petal width (cm)': 0.43259629663198346
}
```